# vs code doesn't show any output for my code

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code, vscode-code-runner

I recently installed **vs code** and **node** because I am learning **javascript**.

the thing is my vs code **does not show the output for any of my codes.

i have tried *everything*!
first I tried running it with just ctrl alt N but nothing happened.
then I installed code runner and here is the problem, every time i run a simple code as console.log("hello world!); it shows that its running and that the running is done but no output whatsoever
[and it shows this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y3z15.png)

and I've tried going into settings and giving a check to the option **" code runner run in terminal"** as I found on the internet that usually solved the problem but I got the same result.
[here is what it shows with a run in terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kGofm.png)

and even using PowerShell by writing **node helloworld.js** nothing happens.

[here is the powershell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/crIBh.png)

it only works when I run and debug which brings me to the last thing.

the *only* way I got this thing to run properly was by pressing f5 and running it by "run and debug" but I don't want to do that every time I need to run my codes bc I'm really at the beginning of learning and I run a lot of stupid little codes(i don't even know what debug means) and yes I know I can make it automatic by downloading some extensions but I really just wanted code runner to work.

Comment: The dot in the editor tab handle means you have unsaved changes. Save the file and then try again?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow your question. vscode only shows the code. Unless you are using some vscode extension to render the code in some way - be it a html viewer, terminal etc..